# Gitlab On-Premise Runner fails to run Codeception with Selenium Chrome service

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, gitlab-ci, codeception

**UPDATE: Problem results from on-premise runner config, works on Gitlab.com; removed all misleading parts of the question**

I have an acceptance test suite for an intranet server with a domain name. I use selenium docker images for executing chrome, codeception is local.
On Gitlab.com this works like a charm, but my local Gitlab Runner won't run correctly.

MWE: https://gitlab.com/jpmschuler/mwe-gitlab-codeception-selenium-docker

The selenium config part of the test suite:

```
config:
    WebDriver:
      host: 'selenium__standalone-chrome'
      browser: 'chrome'
      port: 4444
```

What doesn't work in Gitlab CI:

```
myjob:
  stage: test
  services:
    - selenium/standalone-chrome:84.0
  script:
    - vendor/bin/codecept run -vvv --env visualRegression --fail-fast --steps
```

I `curl`d selenium and the test system and got the same response as locally, thus rules out any host resolve problems.
Nevertheless the codeception test throws for image version 3.141:

```
[Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\SessionNotCreatedException] session not created
from disconnected: Unable to receive message from renderer (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.61)
```

and for image version 4.0.0:

```
[Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\SessionNotCreatedException] Unable to create session for 
   \<CreateSessionRequest with Capabilities {browserName: chrome}>
```

I find the exceptions unsettling. Neither makes sense to me as it works locally with the same selenium images. Anybody a clue where to look?

The MWE at https://gitlab.com/jpmschuler/mwe-gitlab-codeception-selenium-docker works, so I went on debugging and found it is my On-Premise-Runner:

```
[[runners]]
  name = "its-a-me-the-broken-runner"
  url = "https://git.example.com/"
  token = "2c2f60a2xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  executor = "docker"
  environment = ["LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8", "DOCKER_DRIVER=overlay2"]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:stable"
    privileged = true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    pull_policy = "if-not-present"
    shm_size = 2097152
```

What could be the problem here?

Comment: While creating a MWE at https://gitlab.com/jpmschuler/mwe-gitlab-codeception-selenium-docker I could find it is the runner. Will update the question accordingly

Comment: The problem ist actually the `shm_size`. With a default of '0' the selenium chrome crashes after making some bigger screenshots - this is like "known behavior". 
The common recommendation is to raise the size to 2G.